# What does this code in PyTorch do? How can I express it with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, pytorch

I found a code that would solve my problem that looks like this:

```
(self.conv_diag(input_tensor.diagonal(dim1=2, dim2=3))).diag_embed(dim1=2, dim2=3)
```

While `self.conv_diag` is a layer I have defined before.

As far as I understood it extracts the diagonal of a subtensor in the second and third dimension puts it into the layer and constructs a new tensor filled with zeros and replaces its second and third dimension with the new values calculated by my layer.

What I have found to extract the diagonal is

```
tf.math.reduce_diag(input_tensor)
```

but I cannot choose the axis and I have not yet found an equivalent function to replace `torch.diag_embed()`

How can I express it in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/diag) is maybe what you are looking for:

```
tf.linalg.diag(
    diagonal, name='diag', k=0, num_rows=-1, num_cols=-1, padding_value=0,
    align='RIGHT_LEFT'
)
```